# I can't find mysql prompt

Tags: mysql, scripting

I know this is a stupid question, but I just can't find where I can run MySQL scripts on my cPanel. Scripts like:

```
># mysql -u root –p mysql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login to the server with something like Secure SHell (SSH).

See if your cpanel has an option for a shell.

Probably you can just use ssh from your local machine's shell, if it's mac/linux:

```
ssh [yourFTPuser]@[yourwebsitedomain]
```

If you're on windows, try using a SSH program, like putty.

Comment: Just browse your cPanel for an option/icon labeled such, or ask your hosting provider about shell access.

Comment: my cpanel doesnt support SSH. I am trying to enable remote connection from another site. Is there another way to do it if there is no SSH supported?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web-based mysql interface.  It's probably included with your cPanel-based host, if not you should be able to upload it yourself.